# Using C libraries in PHP

Tags: php, c, libraries

I have a library written in C that in turn is build upon the GMP library.

I want to know how can I use the library with PHP?

more informally, say I want to use such library with JAVA, I can simply write Java wrappers for the library.

Comment: You'll have to write a wrapper for it and then compile it as an extension for PHP. You can find more information in [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/internals)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think php's `exec` or `shell_exec` functions can help you out ...

this functions are used for **Execute an external program**

take a look at this...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php